# Time-aware customer service contact modules?

Tags: customer-support, call-to-action

If a site has  module that directs users to call a phone number to receive service, can the module be programmed to recognize the times the call center is open?

For instance, the call center is only open from 9am-7pm CST. The module recognizes and indicates that the user may or may not call at that specific time. Something like "Call now, we're open for x more hours." Or, "Sorry, we went home. We'll be back tomorrow at 9am CST. Talk to you soon."

I'd like to implement this as a nice way to let the user save time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether it can, depends on how the site is programmed.

Whether it should -- yes, for me it looks like a nice usability feature. Only keep in mind that "Call now, we are open for x more hours" requires the user to do mental math to find until when s/he can call. Better detect the user's time zone and do the math, so you can say "You can call now or any time in the next x hours; we go home at y o'clock your time"

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with doing something like this - it is not a big technical challenge. I think you need to consider that there are two time zones you may need to consider - the call centres time zone and the customers time zone. I think displaying something like "The call centre is open until x your time" would be the best option.

Comment: If the time is after the call centre closes, what do you do with the calls? You should have a voice mail system at the least ( in the UK, it is quite common to have a diversion to another number, usually in India, for out-of-hours calls ). So you could put something like "The call centre is now closed, but you can call and leave us a message. We will be able to call you back from x tomorrow ( your time)" where x is not before 08:00. Or even an online message system when they can leave an email-like message, with the option to give a phone number and a (local) time when you can be called back.

Comment: It is a good idea. You need to seriously consider all of the possibilities, but it is a nicety that means customers feel that you are trying to deal with they queries, without the expense of a 24hour call centre.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I definitely agree that it would be great to have a voicemail system set up. I'm not sure if they do. I'm pretty sure they'll accept this solution since it's easy to implement. I'm not the best copywriter, so I'll leave the language up to them.